# DATEADD Only weekdays

Tags: sql-server, dateadd

I am trying to produce a report that will pull a date already in a table somewhere and then show this date with 16 working days added on, below is the code I currently have;

```
SELECT d.CASENUM
,DATEADD (DW, 16, (d.ORDERDATE)) AS [PayDate]
FROM db.ORDERS AS d
WHERE d.CLIENT = 'STORE1'
```

The only issue I seem to having is that the DATEADD isn't adding 16 working days
27-01-2021 Is the last date in my table, so +16 working days should be 18-02-2021
but my results are giving me a date off 12-02-2021 and I can't figure out why..

I am using SQL Server Management Studio v18

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid what you'll have to do is create a new table for the Working Days. The issue is that different countries (and states) have different definition for Working Days.
So the table should look something like this
Date
State (or Locality)
Day of Week
Is Working Day

You can either use a running id for Working Days, alternatively use Windows Functions (RANK)[Rank Windows Function](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-rank-function/)